# WAZUH server 4.2.7 not generating the logs

Tags: logging, server, detection, issue-tracking, wazuh

I setup a wazuh sever 4.2.7 but after installing that I am facing an issue regarding log because my server is not generating the logs of the last 24 hours.

Please respond as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons to not being able to see the alerts.

I will ask you some questions to detect where the problem could be:

1- Is the manager running? What is the output of the command `sudo systemctl status wazuh-manager`? Are there any errors or warnings reported?

2- Do you see any warning/errors on your `/var/ossec/logs/ossec.log` file?

3- Do you see any logs on your `/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json` file?

4- Is filebeat running? What is the output of the command `sudo systemctl status filebeat`? Are there any errors or warnings reported in the logs?

5- What kind of logs are not being shown? From the server itself or from an agent?

By answering these questions, we can narrow down the possible causes of the issue and find a solution to the problem.